# Typo in Hall's 'Quantum Theory for Mathematicians', p. 376?

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics

In the first displayed equation on p. 376 of the book we have the equality

$$e^{2\pi\pi_l(F_1)} = e^{2\pi i L_3}=I$$

The reason for the second equality is that "the eigenvalues of $L_3$ are integers" which is shown previously in the chapter.

It is not clear to me how the first equality comes about. Here the $F_i$ are a basis of $so(3)$ given by

$$ F_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &-1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix};\quad
F_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix};\quad
F_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$\pi_l(\cdot)$ is a representation of $so(3)$ on a $2l+1$ dimentional space and $L_3=i\pi_l(F_3)$.

The most straightforward thing I can think about is that this is a typo and the second term should be $e^{-2\pi i L_1}$ where $L_1$ is defined analogously as $i\pi_l(F_1)$. Though $L_1$ is not defined or analysed in the chapter, we can then invoke symmetry to say that just like $L_3$ its eigenvalues too are integers and so the second equality holds.

But am I missing some other way in which the equality as given in the book is actually correct?

Comment: It looks like a typo to me, too.

Comment: Not here: https://www3.nd.edu/~bhall/book/Qcorrections.pdf